# Возможность делиться экраном Android приложения и создание сессий

Tags: java, android

Хочу попробовать создать аналог paint'а под андроид, но кроме рисования хочу добавить кое какие фичи. Одна из них - создание единой сессии с пользователями и совместное рисование с возможностью у админа разрешать или запрещать рисование. Есть ли какие-нибудь API или библиотеки для этого под Android-studio?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вопросу вам понадобятся java socket для соединения (хотя можно использовать другой способ) и еще отслеживать изменения на экране.

Скорее всего код должен работать так: соединять 2 устройства (вам понадобится сервер чтобы отправлять запросы от админа на разрешение или запрет рисования), отслеживать изменения на экране и отправлять эти изменения на соседнее устройство.

Про API сказать ничего не могу.

надеюсь хоть чем-то помог.(буду рад любой критике)